# Cant play this video

Tags: android, video, background-image

I am trying to make an acitivity with video bg

**splashscreen Activity**

```
public class splashscreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private VideoView mVideoView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
        configurestartbutton();

        mVideoView =

                mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.bgVideoView);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.splash);

        mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        mVideoView.start();

        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

I added the video under /res/raw/splash.mp4

But this happens
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1Pir.png)

LogCat:

```
2018-11-17 21:55:41.407 1775-14397/? E/GenericSource: initFromDataSource,   source has no track!
2018-11-17 21:55:41.407 1775-14397/? E/GenericSource: Failed to init from data source!
2018-11-17 21:55:41.408 1775-14396/? D/NuPlayerDriver: notifyListener_l(0xf1799100), (100, 1, -2147483648, -1), loop setting(0, 0)
2018-11-17 21:55:41.409 14366-14393/com.sherdle.universal E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
2018-11-17 21:55:41.486 14366-14392/com.sherdle.universal D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe5585660: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe55839b0)
2018-11-17 21:55:41.625 1634-1845/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8298496
2018-11-17 21:55:41.665 1926-1948/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.sherdle.universal/.splashscreen: +2s121ms
```

Comment: are you sure that your video is in android-supported format?

Comment: what format is the video in? And are you sure the video exists? You could verify that first.

Comment: the video is in mp4 and I copied it into the res/raw folder

Comment: did you find out any solution for this ?